# DirectX HLSL shader implicit truncation of vector type error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, hlsl

Hi I'm getting an error in one my pixel shaders, implicit truncation of vector type.

Here is the code causing the error:

```
float3 colour = 0;
float3 ppColour = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV);
float4 col = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV);
float intensity = 0.0f;
float r = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV).r;
float g = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV).g;
float b = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV).b;
float a = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV).a;
intensity = r + g + b + a;

if (intensity > 5.0f)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 13; count++)
    {
        colour += SceneTexture.Sample(TrilinearSampler, ppIn.UV + PixelKernel[count] * BlurStrength) * BlurWeights[count];
    }
    return float4(colour, 1.0f);
}

return float4(ppColour, 1.0f);
```

If I comment out intensity = r + g + b + a; then the project compiles. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Try changing 
`colour += SceneTexture.Sample(TrilinearSampler, ppIn.UV + PixelKernel[count] * BlurStrength) * BlurWeights[count];`
to
`colour += SceneTexture.Sample(TrilinearSampler, ppIn.UV + PixelKernel[count] * BlurStrength).` **xyz** `* BlurWeights[count];`

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get this error is, that you are mulitplying/adding up float3's and float4's. You should 'cast' `float3` to `float4` *with float4(float3, 1.0f)* or float4.xyz  (which makes it float3)

Answer (score 0):

Inferring some of the 'extra' stuff that is required to actually compile the shader (uniforms, inputs, and making the code into an actual function), I get the following output when trying to compile it:

```
test.ps(16,9): warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type
test.ps(29,11): warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type
test.ps(29,11): error X4014: cannot have gradient operations inside loops with divergent flow control
```

As you can see, the truncations messages are just warnings, not errors, unless you are using `/WX` to compile. The issue with these warnings, is that you are assigning the result of a texture sample to a `float3`, but the return is actually a `float4`. You can either select the appropriate components with a swizzle, or, change the variable type. For example:

```
float4 ppColour = SceneTexture.Sample(PointSample, ppIn.UV);
```

The reason for the actual error, is that you cannot do sample interpolation in dynamic loops, or loops inside conditional statements. In this case, your loop is inside the `if (intensity > 5.0)` conditional. You have two options, either you can remove the conditional, or, you can use SampleLevel instead of Sample:

```
colour += SceneTexture.SampleLevel(TrilinearSampler, ppIn.UV + PixelKernel[count] * BlurStrength, 0) * BlurWeights[count];
```

Note: using SampleLevel like this will always sample the top mip-level.